# Auto-cloning unique_ptr

Tags: c++, c++11, clone, copy-constructor, unique-ptr

`std::unique_ptr` has a deleted copy constructor, which means that if you have a `unique_ptr` in your class `Foo` as a data member then you must write your own copy constructor for `Foo` and manually deep-copy that member (even if the compiler-generated copy constructor would be fine for all other members).

In order to be able to copy in a polymorphic way, the `clone()` method pattern can be used. Let's assume our objects have a clone method like this:

```
class Base {
    virtual std::unique_ptr<Base> clone() = 0;
};
```

Foo looks like this now:

```
class Foo {
public:
    ...
    Foo(Foo const& other)
        : b(other.b->clone())
        , // init 10 more members that could otherwise be auto-copied just fine
          // with the automatically generated copy constructor
    {}
    ...

private:
    std::unique_ptr<Base> b;
    //10 more data members

};
```

Now, I found a way to auto-clone `Foo::b`, by writing a wrapper over `unique_ptr` that defines the copy constructor and assignment by calling `clone`.

```
template <typename T>
class auto_cloned_unique_ptr
{
private:
    std::unique_ptr<T> up;

public:
    // copy constructor
    auto_cloned_unique_ptr(auto_cloned_unique_ptr<T> const& other)
        : up(other.up->clone()) {}

    // copy assignment
    auto_cloned_unique_ptr<T>& operator =(auto_cloned_unique_ptr<T> const& other)
    {
        this->up = other.up->clone();
        return *this;
    }

    auto_cloned_unique_ptr(std::unique_ptr<T> _up)
        : up(std::move(_up)) {}

    // Delegate everything else to unique_ptr
    auto_cloned_unique_ptr(auto_cloned_unique_ptr<T>&& other)
        : up(std::move(other.up)) {}

    auto_cloned_unique_ptr<T>& operator =(auto_cloned_unique_ptr<T>&& other)
    {
        this->up = std::move(other.up);
        return *this;
    }

    auto operator *() const {return *up;}
    auto operator->() const {return up.operator->();}
    auto get() -> const {return up.get();}

};
```

Now if we use this we don't need to define our own copy constructor:

```
class Foo2 {
public:
    ...

private:
    auto_cloned_unique_ptr<Base> b;
    //10 more data members

};
```

Is such an approach very much frowned upon (for using a non-standard wrapper over `unique_ptr`)?

Comment: There have been many such proposals. Search for `value_ptr`, just to name one. Generally, it is difficult to guarantee that this is used correctly, and so it doesn't quite feel right to belong in the standard.

Comment: By the way, why not inherit `private` from `unique_ptr` and use constructor inheritance?

Comment: *"Is such an approach very much frowned upon"* Is a question that better fits on [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com) IMO.

Comment: You might be interested in Shean Parent's approach to this problem. He presented his solution on various occasions in talks he gave, for example here: http://youtu.be/vxv74Mjt9_0?t=16m2s

Comment: @Arcoth What would I gain with that?

Comment: You could have a look at RMF's [Wheels](https://bitbucket.org/martinhofernandes/wheels/src/17aee21522ce8d07c7a74b138e528fadf04d62ed/include/wheels/smart_ptr/value_ptr.h%2B%2B?at=default) attempt at a `value_ptr`... but note how this will break reliably if you have a derived class in which you forget to implement `clone`!

Comment: I might be wrong, but isn't this question more appropriate to [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: @BrunoFerreira Thanks for the suggestion. It could be, I'm new to these sites. I'll try there when I have time.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about reviewing code. It belongs on [codereview.se](http://codereview.stackexchange.com).

Comment: what if you actually leave the copy constructor deleted, and instead of copying, you move? A move constructor should be defined automatically for unique_ptr, and I find myself writing more and more moves when I use unique_ptr. Now, what you're trying to do is a bit frwned upon, why is there a need for a unique_ptr there? if you want to share the managed object, you could use a shared_ptr, and if not, why not just having the object on the stack? (Ok maybe you are implementing a pimpl)

Comment: @dau_sama It's about wanting deep copy semantics. For example you keep polymorphic member variables x, y in a class A that should be deep copied when the encompassing object A is copied. I wanted this to happen automatically without writing a custom copy constructor for A. Instead, the members x and y should be wrapped into a smart pointer that can deep copy the object by the correct (most specific) copy constructor in the inheritance hierarchy. Look up `value_ptr` if you want to understand the use cases better.

Comment: By using a `unique_ptr` attribute you indicate to the reader that your class is not copyable, but (potentially) moveable. If you need another behavior use another smart pointer. E.g. `value_ptr`. If the pointee is immutable, but fat and the pointer rarely changed, you may want to use a COW pointer. (Copy on write). I think it is better to make the behavior of your class easily visible by attribute (smart pointer) type than to use a primarily unsuitable type in combination with custom code (user supplied copy constructor / assignment operator).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let me first paraphrase what you want to do: You want that each instance of `Foo` has its own instance of `Base` in `b`; in particular, if you copy a `Foo`, the copy will have its own new `Base`, initially with the same "value". In other words, `Base` should behave like a *value*.

At the same time, you can't store `Base` directly in `Foo` because it is an abstract class. In other words, you want `b` to be `polymorphic`.

There you have it: you want a *polymorphic value*. Other people have recognized this need and proposed for C++20 as [`polymorphic_value<Base>`](https://github.com/jbcoe/polymorphic_value). From the documentation:

> The class template, polymorphic_value, confers value-like semantics on
>   a free-store allocated object. A polymorphic_value may hold an
>   object of a class publicly derived from T, and copying the
>   polymorphic_value will copy the object of the derived type.

It has a reference implementation that you can use as of now. Very simply put, it is an wrapper around `std::unique_ptr` similar to what you propose.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your approach is that it is changing the meaning of a unique_ptr. The key thing about a unique_ptr is that it tells who is the *owner* of an object. If you add a copy constructor for unique_ptr, what does that mean? Are you copying the ownership? A and B both uniquely *own* the thing? That does not make sense. If they share ownership, then you should be using the shared_ptr to indicate the shared ownership. If you want to have a unique owner of a copy of the object, you would naturally indicate that by make_unique(*pFoo). With base and derived objects, having the base object have a
    virtual unique_ptr<Foo> Clone() const=0;
is a perfectly normal construct. That is, the derived classes know how to copy themselves so they don't produce a sliced copy, but they return a unique_ptr to the base class to indicate that you will own the copy they have produced. Within these clone operations, yes, you will need to explicitly handle non-copyable members of the derived classes, so you won't be able to just use a default or generated copy constructor. You need to answer "what does it mean to copy something that contains this thing that can't be copied?"
As a concrete example, what would it mean to copy a derived class that had a mutex? What if it were locked and another thread were waiting on it? See why it's hard to give a general answer?

Answer (score 0):

This approach is fine, but you should be very carefull not to clone your objects when you did not intentd to.

Also inherriting from unique_ptr might improve performance

Comment: Inheriting from `unique_ptr` would never help in this case, as there is no Empty Base Optimization for it (it's not ever an empty class)